# Github authentication with node, passport and react fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, reactjs, passport.js

I am trying to move a simple express app over to react, but the github authentication, which works fine on the simple express app (not isomorphic), becomes complicated with react.

There is a button toclick for github authentication.

If I click the button with

```
<a href="/auth/github">
```

then authentication is successful

but  if i use an onclick function and xhr.get, then it fails with

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**Login.jsx**

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {

   handleClick (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('get', '/auth/github');
      xhr.send(); 
   }

   render () {
      return (
        <div className="login">
            <button className="btn" id="login-btn" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
                <img src="/public/img/github_32px.png" alt="github logo" />
                <p>LOGIN WITH GUTHUB</p>
            </button>      
        </div>
      )
   }
}
```

This fails!! with the control-allow-origin error.

whereas

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <a href="/auth/github">
                    <div className="btn" id="login-btn">
                        <img src="/public/img/github_32px.png" alt="github logo" />
                        <p>LOGIN WITH GITHUB</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
      )
}
```

This succeeds!

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');

var routes = require('./app/routes');
var app  = express();
require('dotenv').load();
require('./app/config/passport')(passport);

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);

app.use('/controllers', express.static(process.cwd() + '/app/controllers'));
app.use('/public', express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));


app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

routes(app, passport);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port,  function () {
    console.log('Node.js listening on port ' + port + '...');
});
```

**app/routes.js**

```
module.exports = function (app, passport) { 

    app.route('/')
        .get(function (req, res) {
            res.sendFile(process.cwd() + '/public/index.html')
        })

    app.route('/auth/github')
        .get(passport.authenticate('github'));  

    app.route('/auth/github/callback')
        .get(passport.authenticate('github', {
            successRedirect: '/',
            failureRedirect: '/login'
        }));

}
```

How can i make this work using the xhr? Or rather, why isn't it working?

I would much prefer to use the xhr if possible, since i was hoping that on success i could order redirects and stuff, which is otherwise my second problem... but in any case i feel surely it should be possible to do this either way

Answer (score 0):

check this cors npm package and install it the server : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors
`npm install cors`
Then, in main `server.js`
`app.use(cors())`